# Cannot stream from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, stream

I'm trying to stream data (log messages) from a WebAPI endpoint. I'm using `PushStreamContent` for this purpose as suggested by others. However, streaming doesn't work, what I see is that the headers are sent right away, but the whole response appears at once after it's generated (after 30s when I run the code below).

Here's my code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("notes/problems/create")]
        public HttpResponseMessage CreateAutoProblems(AutoProblemsInputModel input) {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, transportContext) => {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(i.ToString() + " ");
                        await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }, "text/plain")
            };
            return result;
        }
```

What I need is that the numbers are sent to the client every second, rather than all at once.

Comment: Why do you have the sleep?  You loop 30 times with 1 second delays in each loop is giving 30 second delay.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000);` remove that, it's not needed and you shouldn't be doing this anyways when you are wanting `async` support... *if* you do, then `await Task.Delay(1000);`...

Comment: I'm using Thread.Sleep so that I can see that the server is streaming and not waiting till the end. Without it, the server responds too quickly. Obviously, my real code will have a different delay, maybe even a minute or two.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ changed it to `await Task.Delay(1000);`, but the result is the same, it waits for 30s and then sends all 30 numbers.